# sharepoint animated gif progress bar

Tags: sharepoint, animated-gif

I'm quite new to SharePoint and I'm trying to do something that's standard HTML but for some reason doesn't work in SP.

I have a series of pages that were created using the wizard and I would like the penultimate page to show a progress spinner (gears_an.gif).

However, when this page is displayed the gif doesn't animate.

Is there a way of getting a standard, working gif to work in a standard way on an SP page?

(I'm using jQuery elsewhere on the page, in case that may be used to form part of the solution.)

Please let me know if you need any more information.

The jQuery and HTML is as follows:

```
if ($('input[name$="nextButton"]').val() == "Proceed") {
    $('.pageTable').hide();
    $('.buttonBlock').hide();
    $('#processingPage').show();
    $('#progressSpinner').show();

<img id="progressSpinner" enableviewstate="true" src="/_layouts/images/gears_an.gif" width="100" height="100" alt="This is the spinner..." />

<asp:Image ImageUrl="~/_layouts/images/gears_an.gif" AlternateText="This is from an asp:label..." Height="100" AlternateText="with a tilde" />

<asp:Image ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/gears_an.gif" AlternateText="This is from an asp:label..." Height="100" AlternateText="without a tilde" />
```

Many thanks

Comment: Uh, there's no reason for a gif image to act any differently on an SP page to any other page.

Comment: Are you resizing the Gif file in any manner ?

Comment: @Steve. I have tried both with and without resizing (some posts mention that this should work). Unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @Nigel. I wish someone would tell microsoft's sharepoint team that!;-)

Comment: You should paste here how you declare your image (html markup, response.write, etc.).

Comment: please, add details in your question, not in the comments

Comment: try to remove width and height from the markup...I'm suspecting SharePoint to detect client resize to do a clean server resize (which is not supported with .net for animated gifs)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @SteveB. Unfortunately removing both height and width from all three sets of tags hasn't made any difference

Answer (score 0):

It's not directly answering the question, but have you considered using the [SPLongOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splongoperation_members.aspx) class?

It is specifically for this sort of situation, and presents a spinning gears type page.

Keith Dahlby has posted on a [method of customising this page](http://solutionizing.net/2009/07/03/stylish-gears-customizing-splongoperation/).  It's not comprehensive, but might be enough for your requirements.  Effectively, you can inject HTML, CSS, javaScript into the leading and trailing HTML elements and use them to restyle the page.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did look at the SPLongOperation class but getting it to cleanly hit my final page proved to be impossible. It did show an animated spinner but in a standard, non-branded page. And then it failed to find and display the final page.

Comment: Cool - can I leave this answer for posterity as it is a valid solution in some scenarios?

Comment: That's fine with me. Do you know if there's any way of customising the spinning gears page it produces to use the custom branding?

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've found that ASP.Net UpdatePanel controls interfere with animated GIFs. Are there any UpdatePanels on your pages?